# How to disable all user inputs (click, touch) on an android view

Tags: android, user-interface, view, android-canvas

I have a game view which is an extension of View class. In this view I use canvas drawing objects, which the users can interact with.

This view loaded to the layout of an activity. I want to disable all user inputs to the game view, when a button is clicked in the layout.

I tried using

```
gameView.setEnabled(false);
gameView.setClickable(false);
```

But still the user can interact with the canvas objects.

FYI : Gameview class implements following interfaces as well.

```
public class Gameview extends View implements OnGestureListener,
        OnDoubleTapListener, OnScaleGestureListener, AnimationListener
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your GameView implement onTouchEvent() like this.

```
public class GameView extends View {


    public boolean isTouchable() {
        return isTouchable;
    }

    public void setTouchable(boolean isTouchable) {
        this.isTouchable = isTouchable;
    }

    private boolean isTouchable= true;

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }


    //// ... Your Code


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(isTouchable){
            return super.onTouchEvent(event); // Enable touch event
        }
        return false; // Block touch event
    }



}
```

**How to use?**

```
gameView.setTouchable(false); // to disable touch

gameView.setTouchable(true); // to enable touch
```

Comment: isTouchable   should be replaced by !isTouchable

Comment: Welcome to Android )))  In iOS it's just one very short line of code

Comment: Good! If we've good reason to extend the `view`. In my case it just happened to be my extended `view` haha.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this:

```
gameView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

It will capture all user input, and if you return true, it will stop here. If you return false it will assume that you have not handled the event and pass it on to the next listener. You can have a boolean variable that you set to true / false when you need to enable / disable your view.

Comment: This would be better than the accepted answer, *if* we don't have another reason to extend the `view` and intercept touch events *there*.

Answer (score 4):

**Kotlin:**

```
val yourView: View = findViewById(R.id.yourViewId)

// disable user interaction
yourView.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->  false }

// enable user interaction
yourView.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> v.onTouchEvent(event) }
```

Comment: I guess it should be `ratingRange.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->  true }` to disable the interaction